# Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, cdf

Is there a python package for multivariate hypergeometric distribution (including calculating CDF)?

I was hoping to find one from scipy but didn't.

I was thinking of using the binomial approximation to the hypergeometric distribution and then rely on the multinomial distribution that scipy supports.
Do you think that will be a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***General Usage With `multivar-hypergeom`***

Use [`multivar-hypergeom`](https://multivar-hypergeom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), easy install with `pip install multivar-hypergeom`.

**`multivar-hypergeom` CDF**

Example usage from the tests:

```
# CDF method tests
@given(st.lists(st.integers(min_value=1, max_value=10000), min_size=2, max_size=10))
@settings(max_examples=100, deadline=5000)
def test_cdf_summing_to_1(xs):
    dist = MultivarHypergeom(xs)
    assert 1 - 1e-10 < list(dist.cdf())[-1] < 1 + 1e10
    for i in range(sum(xs)):
        dist.sample1()
        assert 1 - 1e-10 < list(dist.cdf())[-1] < 1 + 1e10
```

***Generation***

Use NumPy's [`Generator.multivariate_hypergeometric`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.multivariate_hypergeometric.html)

Comment: If i'm not mistaken this function will serve me just for sampling right?
I need to be able to calculate the cdf of the distribution

Comment: Added on `multivar-hypergeom` which allows CDF calculation as well :)